# Como puedo usar un filtro where() de firestore dentro de un ciclo hecho por map? Javascript

Tags: javascript, firestore

mi pregunta esta basada en que tengo un array de ligas que quiero usar para generar un JSON de la siguiente forma:

```
[
    [
        {
            "name": "Liga de prueba",
            "tournaments": [
                {
                    "nombre": "Torneo de prueba1"
                },
                {
                    "nombre": "Torneo de prueba2"
                },
                {
                    "nombre": "Torneo de prueba3"
                },
                {
                    "nombre": "Torneo de prueba4"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "name": "Liga de prueba 2",
            "tournaments": [
                {
                    "nombre": "Torneo de prueba1"
                },
                {
                    "nombre": "Torneo de prueba2"
                },
                {
                    "nombre": "Torneo de prueba3"
                },
                {
                    "nombre": "Torneo de prueba4"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
]
```

Estos torneos tienen un campo "Liga" con el nombre de la liga que les corresponde en el firestore, pueden haber torneos con el mismo nombre (campo "Nombre", el documento tiene id generado automáticamente), pero el campo de "Liga" siempre será distinto, por lo que quiero que se genere un array por cada liga en cada consulta del firestore.

```
try {
const torneosref = db.collection('Torneos');
const Ligas = [Liga de prueba, Liga de prueba2];
const response = Ligas.map(async(league) => (
                [
                    {
                        name: league,
                        tournaments: await torneosref.where("Liga", "==", league).get().docs.map((doc) => ({
                            nombre:doc.data().Nombre,
                        }))    
                    }
                ] ));
            
            return res.status(200).json(response);
} catch (error) {
            return res.status(500).send(error);
};
```

El problema es que me genera error hacer este llamado, sé que es por las promesas que se hacen de manera asíncrona, solo que no sé como solucionarlo, ¿alguien sabe como hacer ese map para que dé un arreglo con los torneos de la liga?

Comment: porque no hace la consulta fuera del map? es decir... crea un array de consultas para cada liga y la espera con `await Promise.all(suarraydeconsultas)` luego de eso tiene 2 array, uno de ligas y otro de torneos por liga... y con eso ya arma su respuesta

Comment: El tema es que ese array de Ligas, se obtuvo de una anterior consulta, por lo que puede ser mas grande, por eso hago la consulta dentro del map, pues mi filtro es la liga en la que esta parada. ¿Tienes alguna otra sugerencia?

Comment: El array proviene de aquí:

const ligasSnapshot = db.collection('Administrador_Liga').doc(req.body.email);
const Ligas = await ligasSnapshot.get().then(function(doc) {
                if(doc.exists){
                     return doc.data().Ligas
                }
            });

Comment: De la manera que lo plantea, igual debe hacer una nueva consulta por cada liga que tiene... Entonces si ese array contiene 20 ligas, debe hacer una consulta por cada una de las ligas = 20 consultas de torneos... estoy en lo correcto? cuantos elementos mas o menos contiene ese array de ligas?

Comment: O si son muchos, para que no tenga que hacer una consulta por cada uno, puede utilizar el operador IN de firestore. Así, si los torneos los referencia por nombre, podría crear un solo query a firestore que le devolviera todos los torneos de todas las ligas, algo como `torneosref.where("Liga", "in", ["liga de prueba 1", "liga de prueba 2"])`, pero ud armaría este array dinámicamente basado en su primera consulta. Una vez tenga todos los torneos de todas las ligas, procesa la respuesta y los separa por liga, y volvemos a los mismo, tiene 2 arrays, uno con ligas y otro con torneos por liga

Comment: Gracias, esa fue la solución que usé para poder mapear el response de manera correcta, generando un array previo de las ligas y hacer un torneosref.where con ese array y hacer querySnapshot para generar otro array con la info de los torneos, y luego usar filter para mapearlo de forma correcta (es decir, torneos segun la liga)